# Java SSL con certificado

Tags: java, ssl

He estado haciendo conexiones de cliente y servidores pero ahora tengo que hacer otro que use certificados.

La idea es que se comunique por sockets SSL.

Primero de todo he creado los certificados tanto de cliente y servidor con la herramienta keytool de java.

Pero ahora ya estoy perdida ya que no se como usarlos para poder hacer la conexión y no encuentro ejemplos por internet.

Podéis ayudarme con algun tipo de ejemplo??

La idea es que yo solo puedo proporcionar dos datos que son:

por ejemplo en la clase cliente:

```
 private static String CLAVE_CLIENTE = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_77\\bin\\client_ks";  // LA RUTA DONDE TENGO EL CERTIFICADO.
 private static String CLAU_CLIENTE_PASSWORD = "456456";
```

Necesito ayuda para ver algun ejemplo por que estoy muy perdida.

gracias!

Comment: No hay que ir muy lejos. En SO en inglés hay [respuestas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787419/ssl-socket-connection#18790838) que sirven como guía. Eso sí, este formato de pregunta no es el correcto en SO, así que seguramente no haya una "respuesta".

Comment: @Alfabravo le doy un ojo. Aunque por encima no acabo de entenderlo. Gracias!